# welcome event sometimes not firing all the way discord.js

Tags: discord.js

My bot is suppose to welcome a member in both the main join/leave channel and also in the chat room so that way we can all welcome the user. For some reason there's a bug where sometimes it'll not send the welcome message to the chat room.

Error:
`(node:194) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null`

The welcome event:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.avatarURL)
        .setColor(`GREEN`)
        .setDescription(`Welcome **${member.user.username}** to member.guild.name! Consider reading <# {HIDDEN}> to have a basic understand of what we do and do not allow. 
        Come hang out with us in <#{HIDDEN}> and have a good time!`)
        .setFooter(`Member ID: ${member.id}`)
    member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === 'HIDDEN').send(welcomeEmbed);
    const welcomeEmbed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("New Member Joined!", member.user.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(`**${member.user.tag} has joined the server!**`)
        .setColor('GREEN')
    member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === 'HIDDEN').send(welcomeEmbed2); // This is the one providing the error sometimes
});
```

I've tried different things such as a .then or just recoding it in different ways to see if it'll work. So far, this has been the only thing my friends do not understand why it's providing errors

Comment: If you are fetching a channel by id why not just use `<Collection>.get(id_here)`? Anyways the error might be that you have the bot in different guilds, and when that happens those guilds cant find a channel of theirs with the same id (since its unique of course)

Comment: The bot is in one server. However, I will try out the collection function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just fetch the channel by ID using `client`

```
client.channels.fetch("SOME_CHANNEL_ID").then(channel => {
  channel.send(welcomeEmbed);
})
```